# linking directories and files in php

Tags: php, directory

Hello stackoverflow community;

I'm trying to display a few files in a directory using php and coming unstuck:

In my file ('salad') I have three recipe files ('recipe1.txt', recipe2.txt, 'recipe3.txt') and I want to display them so I'm writing the following:

```
        $script = opendir('salad');
          while(false !==($file = readdir($script))) {
             if (is_file($file)) {
               echo "<p>$file</p>";
                 }
             }
```

Unfortunately this only echos to the screen .DS_store, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
<?php
$dir = "/tmp"; // put what suits you here
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

sort($files);

print_r($files);

rsort($files);

echo"$files";

?>
```

source:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php